# getting infinite loop when using useSelector value inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

**Info =>** i am fetching data from backend, the reducer value **"currentUser"** null before it gets the data from database. As soon as i get the data i am initializing it useState() in my componenet.

**Problem =>** Whenever i try to check if there is data inside the reducer value, it gives me infinite loop.

Here is the piece of code

```
     const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer.currentUser);

      const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
      });

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getCurrentuserAction(user?.result?.email));
      if (currentUser) setUserInfo(currentUser);
    }, [currentUser, dispatch, user?.result?.email]);     //Here is issue
```

But if i don't use "currentUser" in useEffect's dependency, it works correctly but the the value don not appear in first render.

Comment: `currentUser` is object? If so, and if you manipulate it reducer in the effect, it create infinite loop.

Comment: Its null until there is no data, When we get Data its an Object , containing "name" and "email".

Comment: Don't chain objects as triggers, but string or number and like so, `obAj != objA == true`